# how do I get Flymake to recognize files in my load-path?

Tags: load-path, flymake

when running Flymake against `~/.emacs`, I see errors complaining about missing files like "powerline" and "company" - i.e. stuff contained in `load-path`.  How can I configure Flymake's elisp backend to be aware of `load-path`?  Nothing in the Flymake customize-group looked applicable.

This is with Emacs 27.0.50 .

Comment: This will not answer your question, but in case you were using Flycheck, this would be fixable by setting flycheck-emacs-lisp-load-path

Answer (score 0):

There is `elisp-flymake-byte-compile-load-path`. Setting it to `load-path` last in your init file seems to be a quick-fix.

```
(setq elisp-flymake-byte-compile-load-path load-path)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the answer provided by [Anders Johansson](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/9111/anders-johansson)—useful in case one is changing `load-path` after the init file has been loaded—is to add advice around `elisp-flymake-byte-compile`:

```
(defun my-elisp-flymake-byte-compile (old-function &rest arguments)
  ;; checkdoc-params: (old-function arguments)
  "Wrapper for `elisp-flymake-byte-compile'."
  (let ((elisp-flymake-byte-compile-load-path (append elisp-flymake-byte-compile-load-path load-path)))
    (apply old-function arguments)))

(advice-add 'elisp-flymake-byte-compile :around #'my-elisp-flymake-byte-compile)
```